# Extract the color of a pixel of screen please

Tags: android

I want to get the color of one pixel of screen

Comment: I already fixed the shouting. Please rephrase so it looks like a question and not like a two year old screaming for a cookie.

Comment: could you tell us what it is that you are trying to accomplish by getting the color of one pixel? Perhaps there is a different way to approach your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't do this.  The screen is not readable at all by applications.

Comment: hack, can you back this up with some references? Not doubting you, just curious to know more about this. Seems like trying to access `Surface` aka http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) would be a good place to start trying to do this? Perhaps not though . . . ? What say you? :)